# Open a new window in Vim-embedded python script

Tags: python, scripting, vim

I've just started wrapping my head around vim+python scripts (having no experience with native vim scripts).

How can I open a new window to contain the stdout from a background process?

Currently, after reading some :help python, the only option I see is something like:

```
cmd = ":bel new"
vim.command(cmd)
```

Comment: Sure you mean window? A window is simply a viewport onto a buffer. Do you want to, say, split the current window into two, and load the stdout of some command into a new buffer in this window?

Comment: @Sarah: I noticed that too, but wasn't sure how to better phrase it.  The latter of what you said makes sense.

Comment: In that case there's no need to resort to scripting. All you have to do is :new +read\ !ls ... Remember to escape all spaces. :new splits the window, creates an empty buffer and runs read !ls on it. Replace ls with something useful.

Comment: @Sarah: bua is already writing a Python script for some other reason and needs to do this from within that script.  (At least how I understand it.)

Comment: Fair enough. vim.command("new +read\ !ls")

Answer (score 3):

Since `vim.command` can execute most (if not all?) ex commands, you can simply call `:new +read!ls` from within it.

`:new` splits the current window and puts a new (empty, no name) buffer into the upper window. It takes an argument `+[cmd]` which we use to execute `read!cmd` which reads the stdout of cmd after the bang into the buffer. Be aware that you need to escape spaces in your command with `\`

All in all you get `vim.command("new +read!cmd")`

```
:python vim.command("new +read!ls")
```

to read in the contents of the current directory into a new buffer in a n cichew, horizontally split window.

If you want to handle escaping of special characters, consider using python's re.escape():

```
:py import re;vim.command("new +read!"+re.escape("ls Dire*"))
```

which should be sufficient for most cases. If in doubt, check its documentation and compare it to that of your shell.

Comment: Doesn't handle escaping, but does answer most of the problem.  Doesn't look likely for this question to get more attention, so I'm awarding the bounty.